# Sparklines in R using HTML Widgets

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, knitr

I want to try produce composite sparklines in R. I thought using HTML Widgets might help:

```
library(htmlwidgets)
library(sparkline)
set.seed(1234)
x = rnorm(10)
y = rnorm(10)
sparkline(x)
sparkline(y)
```

In the JQuery Sparkline function that these packages use (http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#s-about) one can pass parameters e.g. `type='box'`.

To pass `composite='true'` option requires one to set the ID of a class inside a span linked to the javascript function caller. Anyone how this can be done in R? Any alternative suggestions for drawing composite sparklines?

Comment: As of now, this is virtually impossible based on the implementation in the `sparkline` htmlwidget.  However, with some minor modifications, this could be made possible.  I'll try to put together a pull and see if the author might be amenable to the change.

Comment: before working on a pull, I thought I should open an issue on github https://github.com/htmlwidgets/sparkline/issues/9

Comment: Thank you timelyportolio. Maybe should've put it up as an issue on github. I see there that @ramnathv is working on it - nice one.

Comment: Hi, any progress on the composite option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @timelyportfolio raising the issue and @ramnathv for progressing updates by adding the composite function.

```
library(htmlwidgets)
library(sparkline)

sl1 <- sparkline(
  c(5,4,5,-2,0,3),
  type="bar",
  barColor="blue",
  chartRangeMin=-5,
  chartRangeMax=10,
  # set an id that will make it easier to refer in the next sparkline
  elementId="sparkline-for-composite"
)

sl2 <- sparkline(
  c(4,1,5,7,9,9,8,7,6,6,4,7,8,4,3,2,2,5,6,7),
  type="line",
  fillColor = FALSE,
  lineColor ="red",
  chartRangeMin = -5,
  chartRangeMax = 10
)    

# add sparkline as a composite
spk_composite(sl1, sl2)
```